# Powershell Compare-Objects returns wrong results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare the contents of 2 folders using this command:

`Compare-Object (Get-ChildItem C:\compare -recurse) (Get-ChildItem J:\compare -recurse) -Property FullName`

This is the result that I should get:

```
FullName                       SideIndicator
--------                       -------------         
J:\compare\test1.txt           =>                     
C:\compare\install.msi         <=           
C:\compare\setup.exe           <=                    
C:\compare\subfolder\test3.txt <=
```

This is what I actually get (I've noted where objects exist in both folders and should be excluded from the comparison):

```
FullName                       SideIndicator
--------                       -------------
J:\compare\subfolder           => (exists in both folders)          
J:\compare\doc1.pdf            => (exists in both folders)           
J:\compare\doc2.pdf            => (exists in both folders)           
J:\compare\test1.txt           =>           
J:\compare\subfolder\test2.txt => (exists in both folders)           
C:\compare\subfolder           <= (exists in both folders)           
C:\compare\doc1.pdf            <= (exists in both folders)           
C:\compare\doc2.pdf            <= (exists in both folders)           
C:\compare\install.msi         <=           
C:\compare\setup.exe           <=           
C:\compare\subfolder\test2.txt <= (exists in both folders)           
C:\compare\subfolder\test3.txt <=
```

Why is Powershell flagging objects that exist in both folders as not existing in either folder? It's as if I'm using -IncludeEqual with Compare-Object (which I'm not), but instead of the == side indicators I'm getting <= and => instead.

Comment: *This is the result that I should get* - I don't think so; how would it find `J:\anything` in a set where everything starts `C:\...` and vice-versa.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison should be

```
Compare-Object `
  (Get-ChildItem C:\Compare -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Split-Path -NoQualifier) `
  (Get-ChildItem J:\Compare -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Split-Path -NoQualifier)
```

This is because, as @TessellatingHeckler noted, the drive letters (qualifiers) are always different between the two paths, and you want to ignore that part.

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to figure out how to get a full path for difference objects on 2 different drives.

Comment: That's exactly what the command I posted does - it drops the drive letter (qualifier) from each path for the comparison.